# Fundamental theorem of calculus integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: Picture of the question]

I'm not so sure how to go about this problem (it's from a past midterm). I know that you are supposed to take x out of the integral as it's considered constant in terms of t. How would I differentiate after I've taken the x out of the picture to prove this statement?

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the product rule, the derivative is $F'(x)=3x/((3x)^{20}+1)+\int_0^{3x}1/((t^{20}+1)\operatorname dt\ge0$.

Comment: There's an extra $x$ inside/outside the definite integral ... The product rule is needed.

Comment: You're right @CatalinZara.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^{3x} \frac{x}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt = x \int_0^{3x} \frac{1}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt = xG(x)$ where $\displaystyle G(x)=\int_0^{3x} \frac{1}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt$. By the product rule, $\displaystyle F'(x)=1.G(x) + x.G'(x)$ and note that $\displaystyle G'(x)=(3x)'.\frac{1}{(3x)^{20}+ 1}$ by the Leibniz rule. Hence $\displaystyle F'(x)=\int_0^{3x} \frac{1}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt + \frac{3x}{(3x)^{20}+ 1}$. Since $x \geq 0$, second term is clearly nonnegative and the first term is also nonnegative because you are integrating a positive function $\dfrac{1}{t^{20} + 1}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 3x$. So $F'(x) \geq 0$. In fact you have $F'(0)=0$ and $F'(x) > 0$ for $x>0$.

You may also follow the definition of increasing function:

$\displaystyle y>x \implies F(y) - F(x) = \int_0^{3y} \frac{y}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt - \int_0^{3x} \frac{x}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt = \int_0^{3x} \frac{y-x}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt + \int_{3x}^{3y} \frac{y}{t^{20} + 1} \, dt$

is positive because the first term is nonnegative and the second term is positive.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
Notice that in $\displaystyle\int_0^{3x} \dfrac{x}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt$, $x$ is a variable, but it isn't what you're integrating with respect to. It's just some non-negative number, so it could be treated like a constant:

$$F(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^{3x} \dfrac{x}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt = x\displaystyle\int_0^{3x} \dfrac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt$$

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $g(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm dt$, then $g'(x) = f(x)$.

For $F(x)$, you have a product of $x$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^{3x}\frac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt$. Using $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$, this gives:

$$F'(x) = \left(\int_0^{3x} \dfrac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt\right)\cancel{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x)}+x\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_0^{3x}\frac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt\right)} \tag{1}$$

Focusing the blue part, you also need to consider that the integral is in terms of $3x$ and not $x$. So, letting $u = 3x$ and $y$ being the integral, $\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} = 3$, so $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} = 3\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du}$. Hence,

$$\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_0^{3x}\frac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt\right) = \frac{3}{(3x)^{20}+1}}$$

Going back to $(1)$, you can see that:

$$F'(x) = \int_0^{3x} \dfrac{1}{t^{20}+1} \, \mathrm dt+\frac{3x}{(3x)^{20}+1}$$

Since $\dfrac{1}{t^{20}+1} > 0$ for all $t$, the integral is clearly positive for all $3x > 0 \iff x > 0$. Similarly, the second term is also positive for all $x > 0$. At $x = 0$, both become $0$, so $F'$ is non-negative for all $x \geq 0$.